# Custom GitHub Checks With Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-api

I need to create a custom check for tests and to trigger the check through the jenkins pipeline.
for example:
`stage("tests"){ \\ Tests go here. \\ Notify github pr check the status }`

I tried several plugins and some articles I've read about it but it didn't work.
any suggestions?

Comment: If you provide some examples of what you tried and what failed when you tried it, we could come to a solution.